# Extracting differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x(\alpha - \beta y)}{y(\delta x - \gamma)}$$

How do I extract two differential equations (y as a function of x and x as a function of y) from the equation above? I could separate the variables, but I don't see how that would help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $x$ and $y$ as functions of a third variable, like $t$?

Answer (score 1):

I am certain (having recognised the system) that the functions $x, y$ depend on a parameter, say $t$. Writing
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}
\end{equation}
and separating out the numerator and denominator into their constituent equations, we find
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& x(\alpha  - \beta y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &=& y(\delta x - \gamma) 
\end{eqnarray}
These are simpler to form a solution to, and are known as the [Lotka-Volterra System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation). They are incredibley difficult to solve, and I looked into solving them numerically with Mathematica, see [Wolfram's page here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveLotkaVolterra.html).

Pertubation methods are available for this kind of study, for example the methodology in [Rao & Thorani](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-2010/53-56-2010/raoIMF53-56-2010.pdf) present algebraic ways of solutions to the perturbed system. [Evolutionary Dynamics](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Evolutionary_Dynamics.html?id=YXrIRDuAbE0C) by Nowak explains how to find solutions within a more natural sciences bent but is worth the read.